# Reset navigation bar

Tags: layout, navigation

Im very new to Magento - first time actually.

We had outsourced to other developers to change my nav bar to what it is currently

http://flavourdevelopment.co.za/

Please tell me how to change it to a normal thin nav bar like most sites?

Basically i just want to get rid of the blocks and have a normal bar

I have tried to edit the css and i only get as far as changing the sf-menu (seems to be the only one that makes any difference) from a height of 110 to 50px but the blocks do not resize to fit in the container - i see the container hs infact changed but the menu stays the same - i tried changing the LI elements but this is not a solution at all - And regarding your comment - no one is asking you to solve my problem i was asking if anyone knows how to do it as I am new - all i need is a direction. I am a long time member of stackexchange and know very well how things work thanks.

Comment: Hi Ant and welcome to MageOverflow. Please understand, that we don'T solve your problems. We only help. So please describe what you have tried and what doesn't work, so we can tell you what is wrong with the approach.

Comment: Ok cool - i have tried to edit the css and i only get as far as changing the sf-menu (seems to be the only one that makes any difference) from a height of 110 to 50px but the blocks do not resize to fit in the container - i see the container hs infact changed but the menu stays the same - i tried changing the LI elements but this is not a solution at all - And regarding your comment - no one is asking you to solve my problem i was asking if anyone knows how to do it as I am new - all i need is a direction. I am a long time member of stackexchange and know very well how things work thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be more of a CSS question. You said in a comment that you that you "tried changing the LI elements but this is not a solution at all" -- not sure what you mean by that; in fact that is **part** of your solution.

The stylesheet you need to look at is `skin/frontend/default/theme219k/css/superfish.css`, and look into updating `.sf-menu li` rule:

[image]

And `.sf-menu li a` rule:

[image]

The real problem of height comes from the anchor padding. I highlighted the list item CSS because if you want a "solid bar" you may also have to strip out borders and margin.